# How to check if for value in input and if value exists submit form? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a empty input called sub_category which gets filled out when a user clicks on a href link. I need to check if a value exists in the sub_category input and if it does submit the form. My code is:

```
<div class="multi-dropdown-list-1">
    <ul class="multi-dropdown-list">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="ico-media" data-category="Accommodation" data-tag="none">
                Accommodation
                <i class="socialbakers-icons-before" data-icons-before="&#xe648;"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{{ route('data_checker') }}" id="industry_form" name="industry_form" method="post" type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <input id="sub_category" type="text" name="sub_category" />
    <input id="tags" type="text" name="tags" />
</form>
```

and my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // function when click input fill value
    $('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function () {
        var value = $(this).data('category');
        var value2 = $(this).data('tag');
        var input = $('#sub_category');
        var input2 = $('#tags');
        input.val(value);
        input2.val(value2);
    });

    // check for value and if it exists submit form
    $('#sub_category').bind('input', function () {
        $("#industry_form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

The value in sub_category is getting filled out correctly. But then the form doesn't submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was to put the trigger inside the main function itself triggering after the value was input into the input

```
$('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function() {
     var value = $(this).data('category');
     var value2 = $(this).data('tag');
     var input = $('#sub_category');
     var input2 = $('#tags');
     input.val(value);
     input2.val(value2);
     if (value != null){
        $("#industry_form").submit();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that the usage of `bind()` is deprecated in `jQuery` (use `on()`). The `input` event does not get fired if the value changes using javascript. It only gets triggered on user input.

Therefore you should wrap your 'checking if exists', in a function call which you want to call after setting the value I suppose:

*warning: untested code ahead..*

```
$('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function () {
    var value = $(this).data('category');
    var value2 = $(this).data('tag');
    var input = $('#sub_category');
    var input2 = $('#tags');
    var oldValue = input.val();
    input.val(value);
    input2.val(value2);

    if(val !== oldValue) {
       onValueChanged();
    }
});

function onValueChanged() {
    $("#industry_form").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `input.trigger("input");` at the end of clcik event.

input events are fired only after direct user interaction i.e; when user types something into the input and then the input loses focus. When you use val(), fire the event also manually and it should work

Here is working code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNpxwz

Complete javascript should be :

```
    // function when click input fill value
$('.multi-dropdown-list-1 a').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).data('category');
  var value2 = $(this).data('tag');
  var input = $('#sub_category');
  var input2 = $('#tags');
  input.val(value);
  input2.val(value2);
  input.trigger("change");
});

// check for value and if it exists submit form
$('#sub_category').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "")
    $("#industry_form").submit();
});
```